# react useState Using it this way will make it impossible to input Chinese, why?

Tags: reactjs, input

There is only one input box on the page, and I use two states a and b. When b changes, set the value for a, which will cause the Chinese input method to fail to input Chinese.

I really can't quite figure out why this is?

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [a, setA] = useState('');
  const [b, setB] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    setA(b);
  }, [b]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={a}
        onChange={e => {
          setB(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Renderings**
[image]

I would like to know what is the reason for this? Thanks

Comment: The input method will flash a little, I can not select the Chinese characters can only enter letters

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? It looks like you might be missing the Chinese input component and how it's being conditionally rendered.

Comment: Only this input has no other code, if the code is written in this way, the normal input will not be able to input Chinese properly.